# Apply - creating a matrix by combining two other matrices, using value from a vector to select the one to combine column from

Tags: r

I have a task that I am doing with an ordinary *for* loop. I think it can be done by one of *apply* functions but can't find a way to do it. Can you please if it is possible to apply *apply* to the problem or if there is more efficient way of solving it ?
I am aware that I can make udf and *do.call()* but I think it would be the same as for loop.

**The problem:**
I have two matrices a and b, both (m x n) and a vector of length n. I want to create third matrix (m x n) which would recieve columns from a or b based on the values of a vector.

For example:

```
a=  
[0, 0, 0, 0]  
[0, 0, 0, 0]  
[0, 0, 0, 0]  
[0, 0, 0, 0] 



b=  
[1, 1, 1, 1]  
[1, 1, 1, 1]  
[1, 1, 1, 1]  
[1, 1, 1, 1] 



x=  
[-1, -1, 1, 1]
```

if x[k] is -1, c recieves column from a, if x[k] is 1 then c recieves column from b, which yields:

```
c=  
[0, 0, 1, 0]  
[0, 0, 1, 0]  
[0, 0, 1, 0]  
[0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Reproducible example:

```
a <- matrix(rep(0, 16), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
b <- matrix(rep(1, 16), nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
x <- c(-1,-1, 1,-1)
c <- matrix(NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
for (i in 1:length(x)){
  if (x[[i]] < 0){
    c[,i] <- a[,i]
  } else {
    c[,i] <- b[,i]
  }
}
```

Is there any more efficient solution ?

Regards,
P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can either use `ifelse` after making the 'x' as the same length as 'a/b' by replicating each of the 'x' elements. The `col` is a convenient function to do that.

```
 c <- a
 c[] <- ifelse(x[col(a)]==-1, a, b)
```

Or as in the previous step, we create a logical vector (`x==1`), coerce to binary with `+`, make the length the same as 'a', specify the `ncol` in the `matrix`.

```
 matrix(+(x==1)[col(a)], ncol=ncol(a))
 #      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 #[1,]    0    0    1    0
 #[2,]    0    0    1    0
 #[3,]    0    0    1    0
 #[4,]    0    0    1    0
```

Comment: Working! Thank you very much akrun.

Comment: As always your solutions are very brilliant and elegant!